# Is a race condition possible when only one thread writes to a bool variable in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, race-condition

In the following code example, program execution never ends.

It creates a thread which waits for a global `bool` to be set to `true` before terminating. There is only one writer and one reader. I believe that the only situation that allows the loop to continue running is if the `bool` variable is false.

How is it possible that the `bool` variable ends up in an inconsistent state with *just one writer*?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bool done = false;

void * threadfunc1(void *) {
    std::cout << "t1:start" << std::endl;
    while(!done);
    std::cout << "t1:done" << std::endl;

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads;

    pthread_create(&threads, NULL, threadfunc1, NULL);

    sleep(1);

    done = true;
    std::cout << "done set to true" << std::endl;

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you observed a race condition?

Comment: Can't reproduce - program terminates after 1 sec

Comment: Accessing a bool variable is not necessarily an atomic operation.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe an unsychnronised write is not guaranteed to be made visible to other threads in a finite amount of time

Comment: I have tested it on coliru http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f66e96e55cfe233

Comment: @xslr Indeed, the difference is the optimization level - with `-O2` I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a problem in the sense that this statement in  `threadfunc1()`:

```
   while(!done);
```

can be implemented by the compiler as something like:

```
       a_register = done;
   label:
       if (a_register == 0) goto label;
```

So updates to `done` will never be seen.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Your answer is the only one that describes the reason of inconsistency in a single writer scenario.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you post some generated assembler? That sounds like a compiler bug ot me

Answer (score 3):

There is really nothing that prevents the compiler from optimizing the while-loop away. Use atomic or a mutex to access the bool from more than one thread. That is the only supported and correct solution. As you are using posix, a mutex would be the right solution in this case.

And don't use `volatile`. There is a posix standard that states what has to work and `volatile` is not a solution that has a guaranty to work.

And there is an othere problem: There is no guaranty that your newly created thread every started to run, before you set the flag to false.

Answer (score 2):

For such simple example volatile is enough. But for vast majority of real world situations it is not. Use conditional variable for this task. They look weird at the first glance but actually they are quite logical. On x86 bool IS atomic to read/write (for ARM, probably, not). Also there is an obstacle with vector: it is NOT a vector of bools, it is a bitfield. To write vector from several threads use vector (or bool arr[SIZE]).
Also you don't join with thread, it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Race condition means: when two threads are accessing the same object, and at least one of them is a write.

It means you will have two types of racing, write-write conflict and write-read conflict.

Back to your code, you essentially have two threads, one is the main thread, and another one is the one you created with pthread_create.

One of them is a read: while(!done), and one of them is a write: done = true.

You have race condition for sure.

Comment: No. There is no race condition. With volatile result don't depend on execution order (on x86). Wait loop does what it supposed to do. For real tasks you need to add barriers after it, but there are no other accesses from created thread, so it is OK. Anyhow it is a bad idea to do a wait loop, it is very easy to miss something. Conditional variables are created for this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a race condition possible when only one thread writes to a bool variable in c++?

Yes. In your case, the main thread is also a thread (i.e. you have one thread writing and one thread reading).

> How is it possible that the bool variable ends up in an inconsistent state with just one writer?

The compiler is (should be) an optimizing compiler. It will probably optimize the reading of the done variable, unless you take care to avoid that (use `std::atomic<bool> done` instead).

Answer (score 0):

its not guaranteed that the assignment to a bool which is one byte is atomic