# How to kill remaining threads when we come out of any single one?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     5


void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadid;
    printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])//main
{

    int rc;
    long t;
    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);//creating thread

        if (rc){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    /* Last thing that main() should do */
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

**how to kill remaining all threads when one is release**

Comment: If you just want to kill everything i.e. terminate the program, use _exit.  Note that this does not go through any procedures to release shared resources: it just kills your process.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3822674/694576 And if you want to use the hammer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2084830/694576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't bothered about bad design of your code I suggest you try `pthread_cancel(thread[t])` to cancel the required thread. (refer http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html). I think this is a safe way to do it. Ensure you set the cancel state of your thread.

There's another way in which signals can be raised using `pthread_kill(thread[t],SIGKILL)` (refer: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html). This signal `SIGKILL` will kill your entire process. You can also raise some other signal instead of `SIGKILL` in case you want to kill selective thread (refer- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals)  in this case you have to use a signal-handler in the thread (refer-`[sigaction][1]` or `[signal][2]`) to handle the signal you are trying to raise and handle it appropriately. But note this method is rather complicated as you will have to block signals in threads you don't want to kill.

Comment: okk how can we kill all threads using Signals?

Comment: @user1208381: You can't, at least not directly. A threads may be signalled and the thread's signal handler in turn may then initiate the thread's end.

Comment: Have you gone through the link on unix signals ? Did you see what SIGKILL does ?

Comment: @alk `SIGKILL` is an exception. It cannot be caught or ignored. It will directly kill the process

Comment: can u explain with code @vikram

Comment: i saw ur links but have some confusion if u explain with code it will be clear

Comment: If you want to terminate the process by handling a signal then `SIGTERM` may be a better choice

Comment: Try using pthread_kill(thread[0],SIGKILL), in you main before `pthread_exit(NULL)` or after any command after which you feel you need to kill your process.

Answer (score 2):

It is bad design to kill another thread. Standard design is to use a variable to indicate to the thread that it should finish. Each thread should check the variable at suitable points in the code and exit accordingly.

The reason is that only the thread knows when it is a good time to exit and it then can clean up after it self.

Comment: I wnat that way doesnt bother its good or not!

Comment: @user1208381: The answer to your question is here: "*... use a variable to indicate to the thread that it should finish.*"

Answer (score 0):

Implement a two lock solution.
Psuedo code:

```
void *PrintHello() {
  wait_for(lock1);
  if( test_and_set(lock2) == true) {
     release_others();
     /* Do my stuffstuff... */
  } else {
    /* I'm not first. Exit. */
    pthread_exit(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: i_own () is predefined?

Comment: @user1208381 I didn't have the correct sequence in my head for C so you need to find the correct syntax in C. I've updated the psuedo code.