# Can't exit from pthread

Tags: c, multithreading

I have the following code;

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *Thread(void *string)

{
        int i;

        while(1){
        scanf("%s", &i);
        }
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
        char *e_str = "Hello!";

        pthread_t e_th;

        int rc;

        rc = pthread_create(&e_th, NULL, Thread, (void *)e_str);

        if (rc){
                exit(-1);
        }

        pthread_exit(NULL);

do something else...
}
```

I am trying to completely quit from/terminate the thread and after that do something in the main. I tried `pthread_cancel` but thread still does not quit waiting for input.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: When will the infinite loop exit?

Comment: When any intervention from the main function applies

Comment: `scanf("%s", &i);` invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). Is this your actual code, or an approximation? Please make sure your [mre] is accurate.

Comment: My compiler didn't complain about that, sorry. It can be scanf("%d", &i) as you suggested

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For pthread, How to kill child thread from the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822674/for-pthread-how-to-kill-child-thread-from-the-main-thread)

Comment: There's no `pthread_cancel` in your demonstration??? Looks like you actually used 
`pthread_exit`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems you need to solve here:

1. It's generally a bad practice to just unilaterally kill a thread, since the sudden-death nature of the thread's demise means the thread won't have any chance to release any resources it may have been holding at the instant of its death, and then you end up with memory leaks, forever-locked mutexes, forever-open files, etc.  It's much better to have the main thread politely ask the child thread to exit, and then wait (via a call to `pthread_join()`)  until the child thread has voluntarily exited before continuing.
2. However, your child thread will never exit under any circumstances, because it is caught inside a `while(1)` loop, and even worse it calls `scanf()`, which could block potentially forever (i.e. if the user never enters any text to cause scanf() to return).

So, we need to rewrite the child thread so that it can receive a notification that the main thread wants it to exit, and handle that notification.

One way to do that is to use `select()` and a pipe.  In the code below, the `main()` function sets up a pipe (i.e. a pair of file-descriptors, where any bytes written in to the second file-descriptor will appear as output to the first file-descriptor), and makes the output-end of that pipe available to the child thread (via the `exitNotificationFD` variable).

The `select()` call in the child thread will block until *either* the user has entered a line of text *or* the child's end of the pipe indicates it is ready-for-read.  At that point, it will figure out which of the two events has occurred, and handle them as necessary.  If `STDIN_FILENO` indicates that it is ready-for-read, then we know we can call `scanf()` at least once without blocking, because there is some user-text available from stdin to process.  If `exitNotificationFD` indicates that it is ready-for-read, we know that the main thread wants us to exit now, so we break out of the loop.

Finally, note that after sleeping for 5 seconds, the main() function closes its end of the pipe; that is what causes the child thread's `exitNotificationFD` to indicate that it is ready-for-read (because it wants the thread to try to read from the file descriptor and handle the EOF condition)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

static int exitNotificationFD = -1; // could be passed to Thread as an argument, but I'm making it a global just for my own convenience

void *Thread(void *string)
{
   while(1)
   {
      fd_set readFDs;
      FD_ZERO(&readFDs);
      FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readFDs);
      FD_SET(exitNotificationFD, &readFDs);

      int maxFD = (exitNotificationFD > STDIN_FILENO) ? exitNotificationFD : STDIN_FILENO;
      if (select(maxFD+1, &readFDs, NULL, NULL, NULL) >= 0)
      {
         if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &readFDs))
         {
            int i;
            scanf("%i", &i);
            printf("User typed:  %i\n", i);
         }

         if (FD_ISSET(exitNotificationFD, &readFDs))
         {
            printf("Main thread wants us to go away, exiting!\n");
            break;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         perror("select");
         break;
      }
   }

   return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   // Create a pair of sockets that are connected to each other
   // simply so that when we want the child thread to exit, we can
   // close one of the sockets, and the child thread will react to
   // the closed connection by exiting ASAP.
   int pipefds[2];
   if (pipe(pipefds) != 0)
   {
      perror("socketpair");
      return 10;
   }
   exitNotificationFD = pipefds[0]; // child thread will watch the output-end of the pipe
   int mainThreadFD   = pipefds[1]; // main thread will close the input-end of the pipe

   char *e_str = "Hello!";

   pthread_t e_th;
   int rc = pthread_create(&e_th, NULL, Thread, (void *)e_str);
   if (rc != 0)
   {
      perror("pthread_create");
      return 10;
   }

   printf("Main thread sleeping for 5 seconds....\n");
   sleep(5);

   printf("Main thread woke up, signalling for child to exit...\n");
   close(mainThreadFD);

   printf("Main thread waiting for child thread to be fully exited...\n");
   rc = pthread_join(e_th, NULL);
   if (rc != 0)
   {
      perror("pthread_join");
      return 10;
   }

   printf("Child thread is gone, main thread will now exit as well.\n");
   close(exitNotificationFD);  // just to be tidy
   return 0;
}
```

One caveat:  This technique will not work under Windows, since windows doesn't allow you to `select()` on `STDIN_FILENO`.  But if you're using pthreads, it's unlikely you are targeting Windows anyway.